# Seeking index that calculates for Sand?

Tags: remote-sensing, algorithm

On a remote sensing project, I'm trying to identify areas that are sand using band math. I know there is an index for vegetation (NDVI). I was wondering if there is an index that calculates for sand. I tried googling it and I couldn't really find anything substantial.

Comment: What's your end goal?  Are you trying to highlight sandy areas at coastlines? Inland sandy areas? Have you tried image classification to classify sandy regions?

Comment: What kind of image do you have?  Is it visible light, near-infrared, or some kind of multi-spectral product? Do you have the option to specify which spectral bands you collect, or do you already have all the imagery you can possibly get?  Are there regions scattered across your images that you already know are sand and others that you know are not sand?  (If so, you could create a custom classifier for the image.)

Comment: @Fezter: My end goal for this project is to indeed highlight sandy areas of coastlines. But more precisely, I would like to highlight ebb-tidal shoals and flood shoals. 
I am currently using supervised classification to classify the sandy regions.

Comment: @whuber: I'm currently using images from landsat 4/5 and 8. Unfortunately for me, landsat 7 isn't possible due to the faulty images it produces. But from the images from landsat 4/5 and 8, they are multi-spectral.

Comment: Did you eventually get any equation for finding coastal or river sandy areas? I would be really grateful if you could kindly follow-up on this.

Comment: A database for remote sensing indices: https://www.indexdatabase.de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Sand' is a pretty broad category since it's more related to material size than composition. Different kinds of sand will have different spectral signatures. As suggested in the comments, a supervised classification for your particular data/area of interest might be a good approach.

That said, I did find pdfs of two papers ([here](http://www.iiste.org/Journals/index.php/JEES/article/viewFile/4324/4392) and [here](http://www.academia.edu/3171414/Environmental_change_detection_in_the_central_part_of_Iraq_using_remote_sensing_data_and_GIS)) that make use of the [Eolian Mapping Index](http://geochange.er.usgs.gov/sw/impacts/geology/rainfall/eolianmp.html) in determining areas of sand. This method highlights areas of low vegetation cover and high soils reflectance.